# Can't modify the grad of a tensor in R torch

Tags: python, r, tensor, torch

I am trying to modify the gradient of a tensor in **torch for R**:

```
library(torch)
x <- torch_randn(10,2)
x$grad <- torch_randn(10,2)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Erreur dans f(value) : argument inutilisé (value)
2: `$<-.R7`(`*tmp*`, grad, value = <pointer: 0x55cd40aefae0>)
1: `$<-`(`*tmp*`, grad, value = <pointer: 0x55cd40aefae0>)
```

I thought I was doing something wrong (gradients are a little bit tricky sometimes), but when I try the same thing in python it works just fine:

```
import torch
x = torch.randn(10,2)
x.grad = torch.randn(10,2)
```

When I call `x$grad` in R, I get `[ Tensor (undefined) ]`, but this should not be a problem since it works fine in python.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Do you mind opening an issue in https://github.com/mlverse/torch ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug as I point in the comment. As a workaround, though, you can do something like:

```
library(torch)
x <- torch_tensor(1)
x$set_grad_(torch_tensor(1))
x$grad
```

Comment: Thanks it resolved my issue. Going to open an issue.